# Budgeted Independent Vertex Cover

Tags: graphs, np-hard, approximation

Suppose that we are given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and a number $n$. The problem is to find an independent set $I$ with $|I| = n$, such that number of vertices covered by $I$ is maximized (that is, the number of vertices adjacent to at least on vertex from $I$). My question: suppose that this problem's name is $\tt{BIVC}$; is there $\alpha<1$ such that the problem $\alpha$-$\tt{BIVC}$ (finding independent set that covers $\alpha\cdot m$ vertices, where $m$ -- is the maximum, i.e. the solution of $\tt{BIVC}$) is $\mathbf{NP}\text{-}\mathbf{hard}$? Can you give a hint?

Comment: Please state more clearly (better, formally) what you want. There are at least 2 interpretations of your text, with opposite answers.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Can you [edit] your post to state the question more clearly?  Do you want an approximation algorithm for this problem?  Do you want to know if the problem is NP-hard?  Something else?  What do you mean by "easiest approximation factor"?  Can you define that phrase? Where did you encounter this problem?  Can you credit the source where you saw it?  Or, what is the motivation?

Comment: @Dmitry I have edited the question. Hope it is better now

Comment: If $|I|=n$ constraint is present in your $\alpha$-BIVC version, then the answer is trivially "no".

Comment: @Dmitry But why? $n$ is not a constant

Comment: @Dmitry You mean trivially $\mathsf{NP}$-hard right?

Comment: @D.W. The source is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.06576.pdf The only difference that I want the set to be independent, not connected. Is there some easy approach to obtain $\alpha$ (not necessarily as good as in that paper, but at least one such) for which $\alpha$-$\tt{BIVC}$ is NP-hard?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami, yes, thank you, I somehow reversed the question in my head:)

Comment: @Dmitry Can you give a hint? Do you know some specific $\alpha$ for which it is true?

Comment: @Dmitry I know that $\tt{MAX3SAT}$ is NP-hard if $\alpha>7/8$, so the idea is to come up with some kind of reduction? But how to construct a graph based on the formula?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I am not sure... Can we just use reduction for 3SAT? Say, we have a formula in 3CNF with N conjuncts then we just use a standart approach: construct a graph with cliques on 7 vertices and edges between them. If formula has at most $d*N$ satisfied conjuncts, then minimal vertex cover has $(7-d)N$ vertices. Then the desired $I$ (from the problem statement) is the complement of minimal vertex cover. The problem is:in two situations when $\varphi$ is satisfied and when it is not we have different $|I|$. Can we just add $N$ vertices to the graph?In the end I believe $\alpha>6/(7-d)$

Comment: @matheg Can you join [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146494/budgeted-independent-vertex-cover) for little chat.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Finding an independent set of size $n$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

This much is sufficient to prove that your problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard as well.